# Lyapunov spectrum for delayed duffing oscillator

Tags: differential-equations, code-request

I have a delayed bistable Duffing equation with chirped frequency. I have got the chaotic behavior for the particular set of parameter values. Now I want the Lyapunov spectrum for this type of oscillator.

```
k = 0.0; b = 0.5; τ = 0.01; μ = 0.0001; h = 0.2; α = 0.001; γ = 0.001;`
```

```
sol = NDSolve[
        {y'[t] == x[t], 
         x'[t] + γ *x[t] +α *(y[t])^3 - b*(1 + h *Cos[2*b*t - μ*t^2])*y[t] == -k*y[t - τ], 
         y[t /; t <= 0] == 0.1, x[t /; t <= 0] == 0
        }, {y[t], x[t]}, {t, 0, 900}][[1]];

Plot[y[t] /. sol, {t, 0, 900}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image]

I use the method provided in http://sprott.physics.wisc.edu/chaos/ddele.htm and convert the delay equation by large number of ODE's as

```
n = 100;
xp[0] = -γ *x[0][t] - α *(y[0][t])^3 + b*(1 + h *Cos[2*b*t - μ*t^2])*y[0][t] - k*y[n][t];
yp[0] = x[0][t];
Do[
  xp[i] = n/(2 τ) (x[i - 1][t] - x[i + 1][t]);
  yp[i] = n/(2 τ) (y[i - 1][t] - y[i + 1][t]), 
  {i, 1, n - 1}
];
xp[n] = n/τ (x[n - 1][t] - x[n][t]);
yp[n] = n/τ (y[n - 1][t] - y[n][t]);

warm =
 NDSolve[
   Flatten[Join[
     Table[{x[i]'[t] == xp[i], y[i]'[t] == yp[i]}, {i, 0, n}], 
     Table[{x[i][0] == 0.003, y[i][0] == 0.001}, {i, 0, n}]]],  
   Flatten[Table[{x[i], y[i]}, {i, 0, n}]], {t, 0, 1000}
 ][[1]];

Plot[Evaluate[y[0][t] /. warm], {t, 0, 900}]

ics = Flatten[Table[{x[i] -> (x[i][900] /. warm), y[i] -> (y[i][900] /. warm)}, {i, 0, n}]];
LyapunovExponents[Flatten[Table[{x[i]'[t] == xp[i], y[i]'[t] == yp[i]}, {i, 0, n}]], ics, 1, ShowPlot -> True, NDSolveOpts -> {MaxSteps -> Infinity}]
```

This gives no error but the code is running indefinitely to plot the Lyapunov exponents.

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: The Lyapunov exponents are typically evaluated on the attractor. Your first plot shows that the system has not reached an attractor yet. Due to the "chirping" forcing, I'm not even sure this model has one. Perhaps as $t\to\infty$, the forcing term `Cos[2*b*t - \[Mu]*t^2]` will effectively average out to zero. So I'm not sure this problem is mathematically well-posed. Also, in the future, try to include more info on the errors you encounter and link to the functions you use.

Comment: You'd probably also need to use the `MaxSteps -> Infinity` option in `NDSolve`, which you can pass using `NDSolveOpts -> {MaxSteps -> Infinity}` in `LyapunovExponents`.

Comment: I have made a few changes. But the last part of the code runs indefinitely. Please help @ChrisK

Comment: It seems that there are still the same two issues, both of which arise from your forcing term `Cos[2*b*t - \[Mu]*t^2] `: 1) Lyapunov exponents are defined on attractors and your model may not have one.  2) The frequency of the forcing term increases linearly with time, so as time gets large, `NDSolve` will need to take smaller and smaller steps to track the faster and faster forcing. This will cause it to either stop with a MaxSteps reached error or take forever.

Comment: Run your first code for a longer time (say to t=100000). You'll see that no attractor is reached.